# creating many instances of a webpage from one template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm creating a new website application in asp.net. The landing page needs to have a button (or something similar) which the user can click to create a new instance of a webpage. Similar to how a Facebook user can create a new group/event or a StackOverflow user create a new question.

My website needs to be able to create multiple "events" from the landing page which can then be accessed from the landing page, each event should be a template populated with user details on creation.

Can someone please tell me how people refer to this technique of creating many instances of a webpage (event) from one template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core MVC (using this as an example as you have an ASP.NET tag and your description doesn't specify a technology), you can create a template using a .cshtml file. If you are not familiar with these types of files (which are used within the ASP.NET framework), then I suggest a read of it here:

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp

Roughly, it's a file with HTML content where you can easily embed .NET types (such as types from your Model) and .NET logic using "Razor syntax", so that your HTML file is modified appropriately (e.g. with queried data specific to your user) before being sent back to the client. The reference above gives good examples, so I'm not going to waste space and repeat them here.

You can have certain .cshtml files as your "template" and embed appropriate model data using Razor syntax. You can then have a hyperlink tag (for example) reference the .cshtml file using the asp-action attribute. This will render the .cshtml file to the client whenever that tag is clicked on. ASP.NET uses types called Controllers to handle such requests (Controllers are types that inherit from the Controller type) appropriately, such as querying the correct database and providing your .cshtml file with the correct data before sending the result back to the client.

ASP.NET Core MVC modularizes the types of actions described above very well (M --> Model, V --> View, C --> Controller). Here is a good reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2

For other technologies that you wish to use to achieve the same result, you will have to consult the appropriate references.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is a place to get answer on specific problem with short answer. Your problem is general design and programming question, and requires understanding of basic programming aproaches.

For that you should grab a book and read about designing webapplications in .Net.